# CBT Hook dll, to intercept window from being resized

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to write a dll to intercept a window from being resized, but i cant understand how to correctly specify the lParam in this case.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29):

> HCBT_MOVESIZE: Specifies a long pointer to a RECT structure containing
> the coordinates of the window. By changing the values in the
> structure, a CBTProc hook procedure can set the final coordinates of
> the window.

Current code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(
    _In_ int    nCode,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam
)
{
    if (nCode < 0) return CallNextHookEx(nullptr, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    
    switch(nCode)
    {
    case HCBT_MOVESIZE: // A window is about to be moved or sized.

        /*
            For operations corresponding to the following CBT hook codes, the return value must be 0 to allow the operation, or 1 to prevent it.
            HCBT_ACTIVATE
            HCBT_CREATEWND
            HCBT_DESTROYWND
            HCBT_MINMAX
            HCBT_MOVESIZE
            HCBT_SETFOCUS
            HCBT_SYSCOMMAND
        */

        /*
        switch(LOWORD(lParam)) //
        {
        case EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART:
            return 1; // Prevent
        }
        */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of `HCBT_MOVESIZE`, the `lParam` contains the memory address of a `RECT`, so simply typecast the `lParam` to a `RECT*` pointer, eg:

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(
    _In_ int    nCode,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam
)
{
    if (nCode < 0) return CallNextHookEx(nullptr, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    
    switch(nCode)
    {
        case HCBT_MOVESIZE: // A window is about to be moved or sized.
        {
            HWND hwnd = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(wParam);
            RECT *rc = reinterpret_cast<RECT*>(lParam);

            // use hwnd and *rc as needed...

            if (should not resize)
                return 1;

            break;
        }

        ...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How to properly switch between 'events' and in case the width/height of the window be different than a given value, resize it back? What i got atm: https://pastebin.com/mhuj8EE9 The window is not being resized to the desired width/height, just resetting to her initial size.

Comment: There are no "events" in `HCBT_MOVESIZE`, it doesn't tell you WHY the window is being moved/sized. `EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART` is only used with `SetWinEventHook()`, not with `SetWindowsHookEx()`. In `HCBT_MOVESIZE`, all you can is look at the contents of the `RECT` to check if it is in the range you want, and if not then you can either modify the contents of the `RECT` (instead of using `SetWindowPos()`) and `return 0` to accept the changes, or `return 1` to block the move/size altogether.

Answer (score 0):

[LPARAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) is a pointer-sized value. It can hold any value that fits into a pointer. The meaning of the value commonly depends on context.

When handling a [`HCBT_MOVESIZE` callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644977(v=vs.85)) it designates

> a long pointer to a [RECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd162897(v=vs.85)) structure

To use it, client code needs to convert the value into a value of the respective type. In C++ this is done using a cast, e.g.

```cpp
switch(nCode)
{
case HCBT_MOVESIZE: {
    auto pRect{ reinterpret_cast<RECT*>(lParam) };
    // Use `pRect` to read from or write to the rectangle
}
    break;

// ...
}
```